# Swift 4: Multiple network request on Linux

Tags: swift, linux, urlrequest, urlsession

I'm trying to make a network request multiple times and I'm facing with error `core dumped` error on linux (macOS its ok).

Either `request1()` or `request2()` are aborted

```
import Foundation
import Dispatch

func request2() {
    for i in 1...5 {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
        session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in
            print("Entered the completionHandler")
        }.resume()
    }
}


func request1() {
    for i in 1...5 {
            let imgURL = URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Huge_ball_at_Vilnius_center.jpg")!
            let _ = try! Data(contentsOf: imgURL)
            print("\(i) completed downloading")
    }
}

request2()
//request1()

dispatchMain()
```

Sometimes it runs, but most common behavior is finishes with errors like:

**Situation 1:** It executes 4 times and after it is aborted.

```
Entered the completionHandler
Entered the completionHandler
Entered the completionHandler
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Situation 1:** It executes 1 time and after it is aborted and show a stack of the error.

```
*** Error in `./.build/debug/teste': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f84000009b0 ***
Entered the completionHandler
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f841d1717e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f841d17a37a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f841d17e53c]
/root/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so(+0x4ee7c)[0x7f841f5a9e7c]
/root/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so(+0x48e0c)[0x7f841f5a3e0c]
/root/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so(+0x49c82)[0x7f841f5a4c82]
/root/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so(+0x44125)[0x7f841f59f125]
/root/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so(+0x445b1)[0x7f841f59f5b1]
/root/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so(+0x4aded)[0x7f841f5a5ded]
/root/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so(+0x4ad1e)[0x7f841f5a5d1e]
/root/swift-4.0-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/lib/swift/linux/libdispatch.so(+0x46df8)[0x7f841f5a1df8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x76ba)[0x7f841e1736ba]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f841d2013dd]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 1555082                            /root/swift-apps/teste/.build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/teste
00403000-00404000 r--p 00002000 fd:01 1555082                            /root/swift-apps/teste/.build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/teste
00404000-00405000 rw-p 00003000 fd:01 1555082                            /root/swift-apps/teste/.build/x86_64-unknown-linux/debug/teste
017d8000-018ad000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f83d8000000-7f83d8021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f83d8021000-7f83dc000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f83e0000000-7f83e0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f83e0021000-7f83e4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
...
7fff08581000-7fff085a2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff085f1000-7fff085f3000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7fff085f3000-7fff085f5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Environment:

```
Swift 4.0
Ubuntu: 16.04
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I have the same issue but could not find a solution yet.

Comment: Looks like this was already reported as a bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5936

Comment: Will likely be fixed in Swift 4.0.1